# Is it safe to use php $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to get part of url?

Tags: php

I created a login form. Each user has personal login URL (unique URL for each user). For example, unique UL is like this:

```
www.my-domain.com/unique-url-for-user
```

I take this part of url: `unique-url-for-user`, connect to MySQL and check if `unique-url-for-user` exists. If exists, check if username and password is correct. To get `unique-url-for-user` I plan to use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Question is:

1. Can a malicious user use my method to somehow harm the website?
2. Can a malicious user for example type `www.my-domain.com/x` and from the URL, brute force all user accounts?
3. Is there any way instead of $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to use something other to get actual URL?

If a user types `www.my-domain.com/xyz`, I get `xyz` and user cannot give me another URL.

Comment: Does `QUERY_STRING` include the path?? That's weird. I would expect you need `REQUEST_URI`.

Answer (score 0):

I am disagree with @AlienWebguy.

So you have value from Request.

When you want use this value in DB you must use Prepared Statements.

When you want to display it in your page: no HTML allowed -- use htmlentities, HTML allowed -- strip all scripts, HTML and Scripts allowed -- current user must be a trusted user.

When you want to use it in file system(do not forget open_basedir) check requested file in allowed directory(realpath) and filename match to predefined mask.

P.S. Correct me if I'm wrong.